# Testing app on iphone via xcode replaces my app (which is downloaded from app store)

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, download, app-store

I want to be able to have 2 versions of my app on my phone. The one that is published on the App Store and the one that i use to test on my iphone via xcode. Unfortunately when i run my app on my iphone with xcode, it replaces the one i downloaded from the app store.

Is it possible to have both versions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change Bundle identifier of your project to something else. You can find it at info.plist

Comment: Ok thanks, but is there another alternative, because all my certificates (push, distribution etc..) are all linked to that bundle id

Comment: This is the only option. The only way to have two copies of an app is if the two apps have two different identifiers.